Finding a spanning tree with restriction on the weights
Let $G$ be a graph, and let $A,B,C$ be three (positive) weightings of $E[G]$. Assume that there exists a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ such that $A(T) = a, B(T) = b, C(T) = c$. Describe an efficient algorithm producing a spanning tree $F$ with $A(F) \leq 3a, B(F) \leq 3b,$ and $C(F) \leq 3c$.
I suggested a weighing that gives each edge $e$ the weight $w(e) =A(e)+B(e)+C(e)+ \ldots$ but I could prove the property only for the maximal value of $\{a,b,c\}$. Any help?

Are you sure this is true? Unless I am missing something, taking the three distinct spanning trees of $C_3$, and letting the weights be $(1, 1, x)$ (and permuting this for $A, B, C$) for any $x$ that we want, we get an arbitrarily large gap?

@MathieuRundström We are given that the tree $T$ exists, so there's no question of whether this is true or not. (Find the tree $T$ would be sufficient to get the tree $F$ we want.) The question is only in how to find $F$ efficiently.

@MishaLavrov Right, I missed that $T$ was fixed. Thanks!

Set $w(e) = \frac{A(e)}{a} + \frac{B(e)}{b} + \frac{C(e)}{c}$ and find the MST.
With this weight function, $w(T) = 3$, so if $F$ is the MST with respect to $w$, then $w(F) \le 3$ as well. This means that each of $\frac{A(F)}{a}$, $\frac{B(F)}{b}$ and $\frac{C(F)}{c}$ is at most $3$. Therefore $A(F) \le 3a$, $B(F) \le 3b$, and $C(F) \le 3c$.

Thanks, that was very helpful.
